# Building an profile based IOS app for Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm investigating the possibility's on building an profile based Iphone app.
Would like to display profiles as images ( data comes from a webapp ).

Below is example of what I mean its a dating app wich I dont want to make but I really like the image idea,

[image]

- Anyone can advise me on any tutorials/ resources on building specific a profile listing IOS app with pictures like in the image?
- Any opensource libs I should use or would be advised to create a profile centered IOS app?

Comment: These are your app requirements, this is not a specific programming question. What have you tried to do so far? What actual problems do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so experienced with programming but if I were you i would follow these:

1) Create database&server of the application which will hold and send data to application

2) Have a login(modal) view and using that send user informations to server(via a GET or anyway)

3) Fetch and parse data from server in your application(if your app will jus target iOS 5 [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a great class, if not use some XML or JSON parser library.  By the way, iwould chose JSON format to send&receive data:)

4) Use Core Data to create a database(let's say for mobile devices) and make your relations.

5) The data will come from the server and via XML or JSON format will be loaded to your app's database(mean CoreData)

6) Don't forget to use UIAlertView or classes like that to inform user about the username&password wrong enterings or thğings like that:)

For the resources, I bet you will like [CS193p](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-hd/id395605774) video Lectures of Standford University in i-Tunes and http://www.raywenderlich.com/ was a lot of good explained tutorials

Answer (score 2):

Thx Ilhan, that should get me on right track.

Seems I found http://three20.info/gallery wich is used in at least some of these apps and provides the exact UI views I need so I guess I implement that.

Comment: For me the important point is the solvement your problem. That's good if you have found some good tutorials

Comment: I already searched some good resources but they all where blogs the course you pointed to is great and definitly a must have any other recommandations are welcome also

Comment: As i faced a lot of times during learning, most of people just copy&paste the sample codes shared by Apple(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+Code) so they are almost all the same. By the way, i think it will be beter for you taking a look at the sample codes of Apple:)